# How to disable loading pages in background tabs before the user actually views these tabs in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Whenever I Ctrl+Click a link (or right-click it and choose "Open link in new tab") or when I open Chrome after closing it while having multiple tabs open - the background (other than the one I look at) tab(s) begin loading data immediately. I would strongly prefer them to be idle until I switch to them myself. Is this possible to achieve with some configuration or an extension?

Answer (score 0):

You can use first "mousemove" for activating loading the rest or dynamic services. Despite not the very best option, it works.

Comment: Perhaps you have confused SuperUser with StackOverflow. I don't mean doing it for my own web site as a developer, I mean all the web sites as a user.

Comment: crap :) you are right, sorry. I might suggest an extension I have just found [lazy-load](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lazy-tabs/aabgbgciohhaogajcnacpgilhmacdahc)

Comment: The description says "Blocks all requests in inactive tabs (except main document and favicon)" while I'd like to block the main documents of inactive tabs as well.

Comment: Seems like there is a need for such work [here is the discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/25ce5u/question_does_chrome_have_a_dont_load_tabs_until/).